# Троеточие в строковых ресурсах android

Tags: android, строки, ресурсы

У меня в приложении например есть такая строка:

```
because ...
```

в стрингах она выглядит так:

```
<string name="because">because (…, &#8230;)</string>
```

в приложении она выглядит так:

```
because (...,...)
```

Раньше в ресурсах было все указано так:

```
<string name="because">because ...</string>
```

На что мне было предложено заменить три точки на такую конструкцию `&#8230;` потому что так будет лучше. В итоге после замены отображается не так как изначально было задумано. Может я что-то не так заменил или это глюк и не стоит менять троеточие на предложенный вариант?

Comment: *"отображается не так как изначально было задумано"* - а как было задумано? *"мне было предложено заменить"*  - зачем? Почему вдруг откуда-то появились скобки, запятая, второе троеточие?

Comment: @user7860670, задумано так - `because ...`, заменил так как думал что это будет небольшим улучшением кода ресурсов

Comment: Оставьте все как было. Никакого улучшения тут нет.

Comment: то есть просто три точки писать и все?

Comment: Конечно. Юникод символ U+2026 (троеточие) имеет смысл использовать только когда на этот счет есть какое-то специальное требование, например при записи некоторых математических выражений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо, баг при замене. Как указано, так показывается. Нужно убрать скобки и лишний знак троеточия (из там два - один явный, один html-кодом).

```
because …
```

Comment: то есть если я правильно понял, вместо ... нужно написать html код и все?

Comment: Можно код, можно один символ. Как больше нравится.

Comment: код я понял что такое, а что вы подразумеваете под символом? ... - это?

Comment: Есть отдельный символ троеточия. Не три точки, а именно один символ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis